# Unity - How to make gameObject make only one collision when it hits two colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collider

Hi I have question for which I haven't been able to find an answer thus far. I have two game objects next to each other and each one has a collider. Now when a third object collides with one of the game objects then the direction/bounce of that third object takes a different direction based on which gameObject/collider it touched. This works fine for most part when the gameObjects are hit cleanly but when it collides in the middle of both colliders then it takes a direction in the middle, this causes a problem for my game.

I wanted to know how to make sure that only one collider/collision is triggered (doesn't matter which one) when any other objects collides with both i.e. when it hits the join of both gameObjects.

Answer (score 4):

Collision happens at the beginning of the frame so you can detect the collision and reset in the LateUpdate:

```
private bool hasCollided = false;
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if(this.hasCollided == true){ return; }
    this.hasCollided = true;
}
void LateUpdate()
{
    this.hasCollided = false;
}
```

Comment: I like this as a general answer, but the OP is probably going to want to have a more robust way of deciding how to handle dual collisions than a simple `bool` flag. If both objects make the colliding object rebound in distinct ways, then having the engine decide which object collided "first" like this could make the game behave unpredictably, which could lead to frustration for the players.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Will try this.